# Printing large billboard signs in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, billboard

I am wondering how to print large billboard signs? Is it usually done in InDesign?

What does the scale percentage mean? I’m assuming we don’t put the true billboard size in InDesign as it will be too large to create and we re scale it at “10%” of its size - is that correct?

I have already tried opening a large size in InDesign and it was extremely slow so I just want to know how scale percentages work?

Comment: Ask the vendor what they require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use InDesign. I've used InDesign and Photoshop in the past.

The vendor should have templates available for you if you ask. But if for some reason you can't reach them or they do not have templates, I have had pretty good luck doing just as you described: create a 10% scaled version at 300ppi.

Be sure to keep a little margin around the edge for bleed!

Comment: You may want to ask your vendor about the bleed size also, In my experience, grande format often require more than the usual 1/8 inch.